# Not able to run an aplication on windows server 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, foxpro

my problem is that im creating reporting applications in the office, using databases from a ERP, they foxpro(.dbf) databases, so my computer is using windows 7 ultimate with frameworks 4.0, using VS2010 working on Basic, the application itself is doing what i want it to do and runs perfectly, theres 5-6 others computers on the office with almost the same specifications than mine, and when i  run the application  in those computers everything is ok, app runs with no problem at all, but when im trying to run the app in the server who is a windows server 2008, is not running properly, i already checked and it has frameworks 4.0 and the Foxpro OLE db installed same version as my PC, the app runs but when im trying to generate a report im getting this error  "index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection", im using the exact same database in every single computer im testing, i already tried in compatibility mode and running as admin... but im running out of ideas and i dont know what to do...any thoughts?

Comment: what triggers the error?

Comment: I think you should supply some details. In fact, I also think you should try to narrow down the problem by looking at what you did to cause the error, and what the stack trace says.

Comment: Is it failing for exact same query criteria on other machines?  If so it might be corrupted index and needs to be reindexed nut requires exclusive use.

Answer (score 0):

There have been [known issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635024) with DBF (and MS Access) index corruption, and it has been due to the newer SMB2 protocol that will automatically be used when a Windows Vista or Windows 7 machine is talking to a Windows Server 2008.

This problem should be fixed in Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 / Server 2008. So I would ensure that this is applied. If that doesn't cure the problem, your only option is to [turn off SMB2](http://www.petri.co.il/how-to-disable-smb-2-on-windows-vista-or-server-2008.htm) on the server, and force it to use SMB1.